# Is sigmoid function only applicable after dense() layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am making a network which is similar to SE-Net(https://github.com/titu1994/keras-squeeze-excite-network/blob/master/se.py)
using keras, but quite different with it.

Suppose that I want to make some layer sequence like :

```
import keras

Input = keras.model.Input((None,None,3))
x1 = keras.layers.Conv2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3))(Input)
x_gp = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling()(x1)
x2 = keras.layers.Conv2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,1))(x_gp)
x3 = keras.layers.Conv2d(filters = 8, kernel_size = (1,1))(x2)
x2_ = keras.layers.Conv2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,1))(x3)
x_se = keras.activation.sigmoid()(x2_)
```

I want to know that applying x_se like this is programmable. Please tell me if I am doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean "is programmable"?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Sorry for ambiguous word. I wanted to know whether it makes no bugs, and original SE-net used reshape and dense layer so i want to know that reshape-and-dense process is replaceable with conv layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can for sure experiment sigmoid as an activation for cnn layers too but the reason why sigmoid is not used with cnn layers are:

**1. Sigmoid function is monotonic but it's derivative is not therefore there is a possibility that your training can be stuck**

**2. Sigmoid range:[0,1]**

if you are experimenting sigmoid with cnn layers then I would suggest you to use it only for few layers.
You can give **swish** a try.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have one more question. Is applying sigmoid on dense() is different with applying on conv2d() ?

Comment: No, it isn't different. In dense we use sigmoid to get a probabilty between 0 to 1 for binary classification.